# How many different rows can we make?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am struggling with solving this example:

We have $4$ types of flowers, we have to use at least $2$ types and we have $2$ pieces from each type of flower. We place them in a row. How many different rows can we make?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can the length of this row vary, or must it be, say, exactly $4$ long?

Comment: It can vary, so if we use all 4 types of flowers, then it can be at most 8 long.

Comment: Please explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Comment: I am confused about the 2 flowers from each type. If we had just 1 flower, then I would calculate it using (n!/(n-k)!) -> (4!/2!) + (4!/1!) + (4!/0!) = 12 + 24*2 = 60.

Comment: The answer you (initially) accepted is wrong, so I wrote a detailed solution.

Comment: You are right, it was rushed. I altered my choice. Thank you so much for this detailed answer! It is so easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use at least two types of flowers, the row must have at length at least $2$.  Since there are four types of flowers and only two of each type available, the row can have length at most $4 \cdot 2 = 8$. We 
consider cases.

**length $\boldsymbol{2}$**: There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two of the four types of flowers and $2!$ ways to arrange them.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{4}{2}2!$$
such arrangements.

**length $\boldsymbol{3}$:**  There are two possibilities, either three different types of flowers are used or two types of flowers are used, with one type appearing twice and the other appearing once.  They correspond to the following partitions of $3$ into two numbers not exceeding $2$.
\begin{align*}
3 & = 2 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 1
\end{align*}
*Two types of flowers are used, with one appearing twice and the other appearing once*:  There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to select the type that appears twice, $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to select the type that appears once, and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose two of the three positions for the one that appears twice.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

*Three types of flowers are used*:  There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to choose three of the four types of flowers and $3!$ ways to arrange them.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{3}3!$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

Thus, there are

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{3}3!$$

admissible arrangements of length $3$.

**length $\boldsymbol{4}$:**  The number $4$ can be partitioned into numbers not exceeding $2$ in three ways.  They are
\begin{align*}
4 & = 2 + 2\\
  & = 2 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
\end{align*}
from which we obtain three cases:

1. two types of flowers, each appearing twice
2. three types of flowers, with one appearing twice and the others each appearing once
3. four types of flowers, with each appearing once

*Two types of flowers, each appearing twice*:  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose which two of the four types of flowers are selected.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two positions for the type 
of selected flower that appears first in an alphabetical list.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

*Three types of flowers, with one appearing twice and the others each appearing once*:  There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to choose which type of flower appears twice and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose which two of 
the three remaining types of flowers will be used once.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the flower that is used twice.  The two remaining flowers can be arranged in the two remaining positions in $2!$ ways.  Hence, 
there are

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2}2!$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

*Four types of flowers, with each appearing once*:  This is a permutation of the four types of flowers, so there are $4!$ admissible arrangements of this type.

Thus, there are

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2}2! + 4!$$

admissible arrangements of length $4$.

**length $\boldsymbol{5}$:**  There are two partitions of $5$ into integers not larger than $2$ that do not use more than four summands.  They are 
\begin{align*}
5 & = 2 + 2 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
\end{align*}
They correspond to the two cases.

1. Three types of flowers, two of which appear twice, with the other appearing once.
2. Four types of flowers, one of which appears twice, with each of the others appearing once.

*Three types of flowers, two of which appear twice, with the other appearing once*:  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the two types that appear twice and $\binom{2}{1}$ ways to choose which of the other 
two types will appear once.  Of the two types that appear twice, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ to choose the positions of the one whose name appears first in an alphabetical list and $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose 
the positions of the remaining type.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

*Four types of flowers, once of which appears twice, with each of the others appearing once*:  There are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to choose which type appears twice.  There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose the 
positions it occupies.  The remaining types can be arranged in the remaining 
three positions in $3!$ ways.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

Thus, there are

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!$$

admissible arrangements of length $5$.

**length $\boldsymbol{6}$:**  There are two partitions of $6$ into integers not larger than $2$ that use at most four summands.
\begin{align*}
6 & = 2 + 2 + 2\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 1 + 1
\end{align*}
They correspond to the cases

1. Three types of flowers, each of which appears twice
2. Four types of flowers, two of which appear twice, with the others each appearing once

*Three types of flowers, each of which appears twice*:  There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select the types of flowers. If we list the selected types alphabetically, there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose the 
positions of the first one on the list and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the next one on the list.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

*Four types of flowers, two of which appear twice, with the others each appearing once*:  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose which two types appear twice.  If we list them alphabetically by name, there 
are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the first one and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the second one. The remaining two positions can be filled by the remaining two types in $2!$ 
orders.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}2!$$

admissible arrangements of this type.

Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{6} {2}\binom{4}{2}$$

admissible arrangements of length $6$.

**length $\boldsymbol{7}$:** We must use all four types of flowers.  Three of those types must appear twice each and the other must appear once.  There are

> $$\binom{4}{3}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}$$

admissible arrangements of length $7$.

**length $\boldsymbol{8}$:** We must use each of the four types of flowers.  All of the types must appear twice each.  There are

> $$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$

admissible arrangements of length $8$.

Add up.

Comment: I think you missed $\binom{4}{2}$ in your solution of length 4: 4 = 2 + 1 + 1

Comment: @Infinittty  Fixed.  Thank you for alerting me to the error.